# there are 4 places available to sit, how many ways can 10 people sit if...

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

there are 4 places available to sit, how many ways can 10 people sit if:

- There are 2 people who don't want to sit next to each other
- There are 2 people who want to sit next to each other

I know that this problem uses permutation(order matters) or combination(order doesn't matters) or maybe both, also i'm lost because i don't know if this uses repetition or not and  how to approach the problem.

I know that there are 5040 ways for the people if the 4 places are available, but i don't know where to go from here.

Comment: When you say "want to sit together" or "don't want to sit together," does that mean that they want/don't want to be seated *next to each other*, or that they want/don't want to be seated *at the same time as each other*?

Comment: They want/don't want to sit next to each other

Comment: Are there overlaps between the 2 pairs? That is, person A who doesn't want to sit next to person B, at the same time does want to sit next to person C.

Comment: @NeatMath Yes there are.

Comment: @GemorGe So that means that there are only 3 people with special restrictions? A and B must sit together, and A and C can't sit together?

Comment: @BenjaminKeilty exactly, i don't know how to approach that

Comment: Consider there is a love seat for A&B. If the love seat is in, then these are the possible order of the seats: ABxx, BAxx, xABx, xBAx, xxAB, xxBA. If it's the first or last case (ABxx or xxBA) then it's OK. Otherwise subtract the cases where C sits next to A. If the love seat is not in, then it's just 8 people freely sitting on 4 seats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments from the question, I'm going to assume the following:

There is one pair, Person A and Person B, such that Person A is selected if and only if Person B is selected, and whenever A and B are selected they sit next to each other.

There is also a third person, Person C, such that whenever Person A is selected, either Person C is not selected or Person C is selected but does not sit adjacent to Person A.

If Person D and Person E are seated in spots 1 and 4, respectively, they are not sitting adjacent to each other, i.e. the table is not a circle.

Both adjacency and handedness matter in the count; i.e. order matters, and flipping the order backwards gives a different solution.

Then let's do some case work!

Case 1: Person A is not selected. Then Person B is also not selected. Any of the other 8 people can be seated with no restrictions. There are $\frac {8!}{4!}=1680$ ways to do this.

Case 2: Person A is selected, but Person C is not selected. We know that Person B must be selected, and then we must choose two other people (out of the 7 remaining) to sit. There are 21 ways to choose the other two people, then 2 ways to choose whether A is on the left or the right of B, then 3 places to choose where A sits (not four, because we already picked what side B was on), and then 2 ways to fill in the other two seats. This
gives a total of $252$ solutions.

Case 3: Person A and Person C are selected. Then Person B is also selected. Pick the last person (7 ways to do this) and call that person Person D. Now, if A is on the edge (fully to the left or to the right), we have 2 ways to pick what side, and then B must be next to A, and then C and D can be in either seat (2 ways to pick). But if A is in one of the two center seats, then it's 2 ways to pick whether it's right-center or left-center, then 2 ways to pick what side B is on, and then C and D only have one option. So that's $7(2\cdot2+2\cdot2)=56$ solutions.

In total, with the assumptions given, there are $1680+252+56=1988$ ways for the people to sit.